# How to use where on timestamp column in vertica

Tags: sql, timestamp, vertica

I am using vertica db and want to query  somthing like:

```
select count(*) from users where  create_ts ='2015-04-17 05:01:02'
```

where create_ts is timestamp . I am getting zero count however I am having many records.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps are accurate to more precision than a second.  Try using an interval:

```
select count(*)
from users
where create_ts >= '2015-04-17 05:01:02' and
      create_ts < '2015-04-17 05:01:03';
```

Answer (score 1):

From date part to seconds you can use,

```
select count(*) from users where  date(create_ts) ='2015-04-17 05:01:02'
```

Without the date function you have to be specific to the most detailed level.